# Unable to login in salesforce using Force.com CLI on windows

Tags: force.com, force-cli

I just downloaded the force.com cli and executed the command force login in command line but the login window is not popping up. It just hangs until i press ctrl+c. How should i proceed ?

Answer (score 5):

The source code for the CLI tool is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/heroku/force). You could use that to investigate why the popup isn't occurring. In particular, start from the [ForceLogin](https://github.com/heroku/force/blob/64d4291bcaa6473134ab4b3b2492ae4d66759cf2/force.go#L280) method.

You could also raise an [issue](https://github.com/heroku/force/issues) there to get product specific support.

Maybe try the following syntax to do a credential based login. It might be that you're having problems popping up the browser window.

```
force login -u <username> -p <password>
```

Comment: Turns out the firewall was blocking it. I just had to allow access to it.

Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: No equals sign: force login -i &lt;org&gt; -u &lt;username&gt; -p &lt;passwordtoken&gt;